# Quickbooks API: Associating an Expense Purchase to an Invoice

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using the QuickBooks PHP API and am struggling to create a LineItem with an Associated newly created expense (purchase).  The invoice creates successfully, but it only associates a time entry line item.  I receive no errors.

The expense is being added, and when I open Quickbooks, load the invoice, it shows as an available item to associate to the invoice, and I can associate the expense through the front end, but it will not associate in my code.

Here's my code:

```
$Invoice = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPInvoice();

//Setup the Invoice Object
$Invoice->CustomerRef = $Values['CustomerId'];
$Invoice->EmailStatus = "NotSet";
$Invoice->BillEmail = new IPPEmailAddress();
$Invoice->BillEmail->Address = $Values['CustomerEmail'];
$Invoice->DocNumber = $Values['DocNumber'];
            
 //..then add all the time charges as line items
foreach ($Values['InvoiceTimeCharge'] as $LineItem) {
    $LineDetails = $Values['InvoiceLineItems'][array_search($LineItem['WHID'], array_column($Values['InvoiceLineItems'], "WHID"))];

    if ($LineItem['Type'] === "Time") {
        //Unset the type from the array we pass in to create a new Transaction
        unset($LineItem['Type']);

        $Line = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine();
        $Line->Amount = (float)$LineItem['Hours'] * (float)$LineItem['HourlyRate'];
        $Line->DetailType = "SalesItemLineDetail";
        $Line->LinkedTxn = [
            new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLinkedTxn([
                'TxnId' => $this->CreateTimeActivity($LineItem)['NewTimeActivityID'], 
                'TxnType' => 'TimeActivity'
            ])
        ];
        $Line->SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
        $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->ItemRef = $Values['OfferingId'];
        $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->TaxCodeRef = "TAX";
        $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->Qty = $LineDetails['Quantity'];
        $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->UnitPrice = (float)$LineDetails['Rate'];
        $Line->Description = $LineDetails['Description'];
        $Invoice->Line[] = $Line;
    } elseif ($LineItem['Type'] === "Material") {

        if (isset($LineDetails['QBPaymentAccountID'])) {
            $Line = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine();
            $Line->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
            $Line->DetailType = "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail";
            $Line->LinkedTxn = [
                new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLinkedTxn([
                    'TxnId' => $this->CreatePurchase(
                        [
                            "PaymentAccount" => $LineDetails['QBPaymentAccountID'],
                            "LineItemCategory" => $LineDetails['QBExpenseCategoryID'],
                            "LineItemValue" => (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'],
                            "CostID" => $LineDetails['WHID'],
                            "CustomerId" => $Values['CustomerId'],
                            "Description" => $LineDetails['ExpenseDesc']
                        ]
                        )['NewPurchaseID'], 
                    'TxnType' => 'Expense'
                ])
            ];

            $Line->AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPAccountBasedExpenseLineDetail();
            $Line->AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail->AccountRef = $LineDetails['QBPaymentAccountID'];
            $Line->AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail->CustomerRef = $Values['CustomerId'];
            $Line->AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail->BillableStatus = "Billable";

            $Invoice->Line[] = $Line;
        } else {
            $Line = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine();
            $Line->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
            $Line->DetailType = "SalesItemLineDetail";
            $Line->SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
            $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->ItemRef = $Values['OfferingId'];
            $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
            $Line->Description = $LineDetails['Description'];
            $Invoice->Line[] = $Line;
        }
    }

}
            
// Create the new Invoice in QuickBooks
$NewInvoice = $this->_DataService->Add($Invoice);

$error = $this->_DataService->getLastError();
```

And for thoroughness, here is the function to create the expense purchase:

```
//Adds a purchase record to quickbooks (initially for expenses) 
public function CreatePurchase($Values) {

    // Create a new QuickBooks's Invoice & Line object 
    $PurchaseItem = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Purchase();

    $PurchaseValues = [
        'AccountRef' => [
            'value' => $Values['PaymentAccount'], 
        ],
        'PaymentType' => 'Cash',
        'TotalAmt' => $Values['LineItemValue'], // The total amount of the expense
        'Line' => [
            [
                'Amount' => $Values['LineItemValue'], // The amount of the line item
                'DetailType' => 'AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail',
                'AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail' => [
                    'AccountRef' => [
                        'value' => $Values['LineItemCategory'], // The ID of the expense account for the line item
                    ],
                    'CustomerRef' => [
                        'value' => $Values['CustomerId']
                    ],
                    "BillableStatus" => "Billable"
                ],
                'Description' => $Values['Description']
            ]
        ]
    ];
    
     // Create the new Invoice in QuickBooks
    $NewPurchase = $this->_DataService->Add($PurchaseItem->create($PurchaseValues));

    $error = $this->_DataService->getLastError();

    if ($error) {
        //throw new Exception($error->getIntuitErrorDetail());
        return ["status" => false, "error" => $error->getIntuitErrorDetail()];
    } else {
        return ["status" => true, "NewPurchaseID" => $NewPurchase->Id, "NewPurchaseObject" => $NewPurchase, "XrefID" => $XrefUpdateResult];
    }

}
```

It makes no sense to me how the line item with the time charge creates the time charge, and associates it to the invoice, yet adding the expense purchase does not.  This has been very frustrating as everything creates it is just NOT linking, and I'm not getting any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have not found very much in terms of good documentation on this.

Thanks.

Comment: My presumption is it isn't linking because your `$Values['OfferingId']` should be a reference to the `\QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Item` identifier. From memory, it should also be a key paired array of `['value' => $item->id]`. [See example](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-CRUD-PHP/blob/master/CRUD_Examples/Item/ItemCreate.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, that part of the code is working as it is written.  That is the part of the code that links a time entry to a line item.  The problem is when linking a purchase item as an expense to a line item to an invoice that does not appear.  The code after "elseif ($LineItem['Type'] === "Material")".

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution should anyone else run into this problem and given there is no documentation anywhere on this topic (and chat GPT is not smart enough for this one) I figured I'd share it here.  After much trial and error, and a little poking around to reverse engineer the object coming back from QuickBooks when creating the invoice from the front end, I realized that you need to:

1. Create the Expense Line Item against the Invoice as a standard Sales Line Item Detail
2. Create the Purchase item as I had done, but when you link it to the line item of the invoice you are linking a transaction type of "ReimburseCharge" not "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail" as is the type that the actual purchase object is
3. When linking it back to the line item, you then need to get the purchase object's linked transaction id, which will be the ReimburseCharge object id

Here is my updated code (just for the expense reimbursing section):

```
if (isset($LineDetails['QBPaymentAccountID'])) {
    $Line = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine();
    $Line->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
    $Line->DetailType = "SalesItemLineDetail";

    $CreatedExpense = $this->CreatePurchase(
                [
                    "PaymentAccount" => $LineDetails['QBPaymentAccountID'],
                    "LineItemCategory" => $LineDetails['QBExpenseCategoryID'],
                    "LineItemValue" => (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'],
                    "CostID" => $LineDetails['WHID'],
                    "CustomerId" => $Values['CustomerId'],
                    "Description" => $LineDetails['ExpenseDesc']
                ])['NewPurchaseObject'];

    $Line->LinkedTxn = [
        new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLinkedTxn([
            'TxnId' => $CreatedExpense->LinkedTxn->TxnId, 
            'TxnType' => 'ReimburseCharge',
            'TxnLineId' => $CreatedExpense->Line->Id
        ])
    ]; 

    $Line->SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
    $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
    $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->TaxCodeRef = "NON";

    $Line->Description = $LineDetails['Description'];

    $Invoice->Line[] = $Line;
} else {
    $Line = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine();
    $Line->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
    $Line->DetailType = "SalesItemLineDetail";
    $Line->SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPSalesItemLineDetail();
    $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->ItemRef = $Values['OfferingId'];
    $Line->SalesItemLineDetail->Amount = (float)$LineDetails['LineItemValue'];
    $Line->Description = $LineDetails['Description'];
    $Invoice->Line[] = $Line;
}
```

Comment: did this ever show you a "chain link" icon on the line item when viewing the invoice in the UI? When you link them manually via the UI it's there, but never via the API.